# Why isn't is_page working when I put it in the functions.php file?

Tags: functions, pages, conditional-content

I have page called "Apple", the page's ID id 2533.

In page.php file I have line:

```
echo $bannerimg
```

And this function in functions.php:

```
if ( is_page( '2533' ) ) {    
    // also tested with 'Apple'
    $bannerimg = 'apple.jpg';

} elseif ( is_page( 'test' ) ) {    
    $bannerimg = 'test.jpg';

} elseif ( is_page( 'admissions' ) ) { 
    $bannerimg = 'admissions.jpg';

} else { 
    $bannerimg = 'home.jpg';
}
```

The point is the $bannerimg echoes "home.jpg" on every page, including Apple, test and admissions.

I've even checked all the IDs using the_ID & $page->ID. Nothing. So I guess there's something wrong with the code above?

Comment: A solution in following thread helped me solving similar issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225359/is-page-template-is-page-in-functions-php-not-working/225369

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`functions.php` is processed way before you can know which page is being loaded. Instead of assigning value to variable put your code into function and use that function in `page.php` template.

Comment: I've tried with this code inside of a function as well, but seems like it returns nothing. I know putting it all into page.php should help, but is not so elegant.

Comment: I dont use id's for page reference but codex shows that the id of the page has no single quotes, have you tried that? `is_page();
// When any single Page is being displayed.

is_page(42);
// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.

is_page('Contact');
// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.

is_page('about-me');
// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

is_page(array(42,'about-me','Contact'));
// Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID 42.` probably not the case but worth a shot

Comment: @Martin quotes are not entirely correct, but won't break anything either - it is loosely compared by default (without checking if type matches)

Comment: What if you want to add a filter to the query? You can't do that in the template. But you can't do it in the functions.php file, either!

Comment: @reggie why not? You should probably ask new question about it. :)

Answer (score 10):

`get_header` ***should*** work if you want to leave it in `functions.php`

```
add_action('get_header', function() {
    if ( is_page( '2533' ) ) {    
    // also tested with 'Apple'
        $bannerimg = 'apple.jpg';

    } elseif ( is_page( 'test' ) ) {    
        $bannerimg = 'test.jpg';

    } elseif ( is_page( 'admissions' ) ) { 
        $bannerimg = 'admissions.jpg';

    } else { 
        $bannerimg = 'home.jpg';
    }  
});
```

Comment: Why exactly does this work? It's the only thing we've found to successfully make is_page() work within functions file.

Answer (score 4):

Extending what @Rarst posted and you commented  , a more elegant solution would be to create your own filter inside page.php and hook to it from a function inside the functions.php, for example:

in you page.php

```
$bannerimg = apply_filters('my_bannerimg','defualt_img.jpg');
```

and in your functions.php

```
add_filter('my_bannerimg','what_page_is_it');

function what_page_is_it($img){
    if ( is_page( '2533' ) ) {    
        return 'apple.jpg';
    } elseif ( is_page( 'test' ) ) {    
        return 'test.jpg';
    } elseif ( is_page( 'admissions' ) ) { 
        return 'admissions.jpg';
    } else { 
        return 'home.jpg';
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php, change name of script someCode and name of page:

```
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_theme_js');

    function wpt_theme_js() { 
        if ( is_page('somePage') ) {
            wp_enqueue_script('someCode_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/someCode.js', '', '', true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In functions.php `is_page()` with the `add_action('wp', 'your_function_name');` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly declared `wp_head();` etc in your theme?

Also, `is_page` accepts an ID without quotes.

The problem may also be the fact you are already on the page template so it is a page, you may be better of querying the `$post->ID` or set up `page-apple.php`

Comment: `is_page()` can accept ID as integer as well

Comment: yeah but an int shouldn't be quoted

Comment: That's strange, because I see quotes everywhere: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: and it's a bad practice.

Comment: I agree, the integer should not be quoted. But PHP will not mind either way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function at a point in the WordPress process *after the Query is set up*.

In `functions.php`:

```
function mytheme_get_banner_img() {
    if ( is_page( '2533' ) ) {    
        // also tested with 'Apple'
        $bannerimg = 'apple.jpg';

    } elseif ( is_page( 'test' ) ) {    
        $bannerimg = 'test.jpg';

    } elseif ( is_page( 'admissions' ) ) { 
        $bannerimg = 'admissions.jpg';

    } else { 
        $bannerimg = 'home.jpg';
    }  
    return $bannerimg;
}
```

Then, in your `page.php` template file, wherever you need to return/output `$bannerimg`:

```
<?php
$bannerimg = mytheme_get_banner_img();
?>
```

Then, you can do whatever you need to with `$bannerimg`: drop it in an `<img>` tag, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```php
if( is_page('Vehicle') ) {
    // code here
}
```

*this will definitely work on page.php file please move there and check.*

**[NB]:** // replace your page id | slug | array with **Vehicle**

Comment: I don't think this adds anything to the existing answers, and IMO the accepted answer explains it better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook the `wp` function.

**Important note**: Note that if you hook to the `init` function, is_page will **not work**

```
add_filter('wp', 'pre_fix_function_is_page');

function pre_fix_function_is_page()
{

    if ( is_page( '2533' ) ) {
        // also tested with 'Apple'
        $bannerimg = 'apple.jpg';

    } elseif ( is_page( 'test' ) ) {
        $bannerimg = 'test.jpg';

    } elseif ( is_page( 'admissions' ) ) {
        $bannerimg = 'admissions.jpg';

    } else {
        $bannerimg = 'home.jpg';
    }
}
```