# wp_set_object_terms not working in functions.php with custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using custom fields with custom taxonomy... And needed to asign new post to custom category.

As you know default wp_insert_post not working with 'post_category' with custom posts. So we need to asign with wp_set_object_terms.

But there is big problem, when i put for example in function.php file this code:

wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, array(1,5), 'custom_cat_taxonomy')

its not working at all

and the error is: WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] =>

when I put this code in for example in single.php it works and assigns category to post.

any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: I found that when I register a new taxonomy. In functions.php i printed all taxonomy and there are no registered taxonomies, only default taxonomies. Array ( [category] => category [post_tag] => post_tag [nav_menu] => nav_menu [link_category] => link_category [post_format] => post_format )

Comment: What action are you hooking your taxonomy registration function to?

Comment: You can make logic in `functions.php` file and call it on specific template. See this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/why-isnt-is-page-working-when-i-put-it-in-the-functions-php-file)