# Minimum allowed comment length only on a specific page

Tags: comments

This is the function I use to only allow comments longer than 60 chars:

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpb_preprocess_comment' );
function wpb_preprocess_comment($comment) {
if ( strlen( $comment['comment_content'] ) < 60 ) {
    wp_die('Minimum allowed comment length is 60 characters.');
}
return $comment;
}
```

How do I make this filter apply to comments only on a specific page, say, is_page(42)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is_page() is not available at that point try using global $post that way the post ID should be available for comparison.

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpb_preprocess_comment' );
function wpb_preprocess_comment($comment) {
global $post;
if ((strlen( $comment['comment_content'] ) < 60 ) && ($post->ID == 42)) {
    wp_die('Minimum allowed comment length is 60 characters.');
}
return $comment;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like is_page is not available at that point. Look at this post -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/why-isnt-is-page-working-when-i-put-it-in-the-functions-php-file

Comment: I don't really need to necessarily use is_page(). Any other workable way of specifying post id within the function should be sufficient.

Comment: Updated the answer.