# Is there a hack for using is_page() within the function.php file?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, customization, ajax

I've created a function in my `functions.php` that's called when the `submit_form` event is fired on the front-end. Here is the code:

```
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_form", "submit_my_form" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_submit_form", "submit_my_form" );
function submit_my_form() {

    $send_to  = array( "test_address@test.com" );

    if ( is_page( "contact" ) ) {
        $subject = "This subject line is for the Contact page.";
    } else {
        $subject = "This subject line is for every other page.";
    }

    $message  = "Name: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Phone: " . $_POST["tel"] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "City: " . $_POST["city"] . ", " . $_POST["state"] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Message: " . $_POST["message"] . "\r\n";

    wp_mail( $send_to, $subject, $message );
    wp_die();
} ?>
```

The problem is that I need my `$subject` and possibly `$send_to` variables to vary, based on the page. The answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/why-isnt-is-page-working-when-i-put-it-in-the-functions-php-file) but it still doesn't address my problem. Is there a way to hack the `is_page()` function so it's functional within the ``functions.php`file or is there a workaround that doesn't involve using`is_page()` at all?

Comment: Whatever data you want to operate on needs to be passed with the AJAX data. `is_page` will never work with an AJAX request, because it's not a page- you're making the request *from* a page, it's an entirely different http request.

Comment: to extend Milo's comment, you have to add the page name as an argument of the http request of the AJAX call

Answer (score 1):

// You can retrieve your link and get the id (contact ID=4 for example)

```
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$page_id = url_to_postid($link);

    if (page_id == '4'){
        $subject = "This subject line is for the Contact page.";
    } else {
        $subject = "This subject line is for every other page.";
    }
```