# is_page condition not working

Tags: pages

The `is_page()` with post id, post slug isn't working. Below is the code i have been using in divi child theme at the end of the `functions.php` file.

```
function addingcattocatlist($cat_list){

        if ( is_page('blog') ) {
            $cat_list = 'blog: '. '' .$cat_list;
        }   
        return $cat_list;
}
add_filter('the_category' , 'addingcattocatlist', 10);
```

Comment: are you using a custom page template? whats the file name?

Comment: I am not using custom page template. I just want that on /blog/ page , when the categories are listed, blog:  text needs to be added before the categories list.

Comment: Are the conditionals actually available when that filter is being called?

Comment: is 'blog' the page you have set as 'posts page'?

Comment: @Welcher , Sorry i am not sure if the conditions are actually available when that filter is called. It might be the issue. how can i check it ?

Comment: @Michael , it's a custom page. just a /blog page and It's not set as 'posts page'.

Comment: re: 'blog shortcode has been used on it. ... but a page with blog shortcode on it that can list posts with different options' - is that shortcode theme specific? in that case, the problem might be caused by that shortcode function, and you might need to ask the theme's developer for help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I figured out the solution and posted it here as Answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everything else
}
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: I have already researched this on internet. Please, reply why the is_page isn't working in the above case. tested by entering the id and slug there. and it didn't worked !

Answer (score 1):

OK @Muyassir S. - we are missing some information to understand the problem.

We basicly dont know if the "page" you are talking about is a category page, Your home page or a custom page - meaning: which file is being used to show that blog?

here are two possible solutions.

**If we are talking about a category / page with slug:**

```
if(is_category('blog')) {
   // add whatever you want here
}
```

- should be placed inside category.php template

**If you went to: Settings > Reading**
and set the posts page over there then its a page and can be accesses like this.

```
$blogPgid = get_option('page_for_posts');

if(get_the_ID() == $blogPgid) {
       // add whatever you want here
}
```

- should be placed inside page.php template.

Let me know if this helps

EDIT 1:
here is what i would do.

1st. Just copy page.php in your theme and name the new copy page-blog.php Now, add a in the top of that page these tag (above everything).

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog Page
*/
?>
```

2nd. go back to that page in WP admin and pick that page template. Now you have a page / file that you can control and add whichever specific stuff you'd like.

Comment: It's a custom page using the default template.

Comment: what makes its custom? did you try the second option?

Comment: a page /blog has been created and with divi theme builder, blog shortcode has been used on it. It's actually not the default posts page but a page with blog shortcode on it that can list posts with different options.

Comment: OMG... didnt knew that - did you just added that to your question?. In any case - well, see edit

Comment: Thank you, it helped. Also i found the reason why the is_page isn't working in functions.php file on the following link in stack. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/why-isnt-is-page-working-when-i-put-it-in-the-functions-php-file?rq=1

Comment: is_page is a check which means "if this file / content is a page"... You can also use it to check for a specific page by id, slug, name like so: if(is_page('example')) {echo 'do something';}  -  this is unrelated to what you wanted to do. You could use a check built into wordpress named "has_shortcode" but my way is easier since this is just one page.

Comment: yes, you're right.

Comment: My pleasue - dont forget to accept answer which will mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

functions.php is processed way before you can know which page is being loaded. Instead of assigning value to variable put your code into function and use that function in page.php template.

[Why isn't is_page working when I put it in the functions.php file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21418/why-isnt-is-page-working-when-i-put-it-in-the-functions-php-file)