# is_page_template & is_page in functions.php not working

Tags: page-template, wp-enqueue-script

I use the following script to call the maps JavaScript in the `page-about.php` template. But its actually not working. The scripts are executed nowhere:

```
// Load maps scripts
function maps_scripts()
{   
    // If query if current Page is not wp-login-php or admin page
    if ( is_page_template('page-about.php') ) {
        wp_register_script('gmapsapi', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', array(), '1.0.0', true); 
        wp_enqueue_script('gmapsapi');

        wp_register_script('gmaps', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gmaps.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true); 
        wp_enqueue_script('gmaps'); 

        wp_register_script('map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map.js', array(), '1.0.0', true); 
        wp_enqueue_script('map'); 
    } 
}

add_action('init', 'maps_scripts');
```

I also tried with `is_page()` but its not working. When I delete the `if` statements the scripts are loaded on all pages.

Comment: use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `init`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead on `init`. This will ensure you the template is already loaded.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maps_scripts');
```

Or you try to check the template using `get_page_template_slug()` instead of `is_page_template`:

```
$tmp = get_page_template_slug($post_id); // provide page/post ID
if('page-about.php' == $tmp) {
    // enqueue scripts here
}
```

Note that you don't need to register scripts before enqueueing them. Simply pass all the parameters of `wp_register_script` directly to the `wp_enqueue_script` (see the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)).

Comment: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maps_scripts'); solved the problem. Thank you so much!